# jQuery Live function help needed

Tags: jquery

Whats the use of `live` in jQuery? I mean when exactly do we use it.

I was trying to add an `onclick` event to an anchor tag, but it was not working. Then I used:

```
$('#Register').live('click', function (e) {
    $("#storytellerregistration").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

and this worked. When exactly should we use `live` function?

Comment: which version of JQuery are you using?

Comment: i m using jquery-1.7.1.min.js

Comment: Did you look at the [jQuery doco for `.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)? (If you're not sure what _function xyz()_ from the _abc library_ does, how about googling "xyz abc"?)

Comment: @Imran-Can you show us the html part where you're trying to add click event?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Condition onclick jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20826467/condition-onclick-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Quoting Docs:](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

(Emphasis mine)

> Description: Attach an event handler for all elements which match the
>   current selector, now **and in the future**.

Notice the `and in the future` part, it refers to those elements that are not present but will be added in future.

So you use `live()` for those elements that you add **dynamically**/later in your page via JS/jQuery.

In conclusion, `live()` works for elements that are present when document was loaded and also those which are added **later** via JS/jQuery.

Let's assume we create a div and attach it to body:

```
$('<div />').attr('id', 'mydiv').append('body');
```

Now since we added this element ourself later/afer page load, we will have to use `live()` for such element.

```
$('#mydiv').live('click', function(){ ... });
```

---

**Note:** The `live()` is deprecated method and won't work in future versions of jQuery. Start using [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method instead :)

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `.live()` (or `.on()` since jQuery 1.7) is that it listen for events from elements available in the DOM the moment the function is called, **but also from future elements** if you dynamically add an element to the DOM in the future that matches the selector.

Compared to `.click()` which will only listen for click-events from DOM-elements that match your selector and that are available in the DOM when the method is called.

Answer (score 0):

Live is now deprecated in the latest version jQuery.It has been replaced with 'on'. The purpose of 'live' and 'on' is to be able to attach an event handler to a parent element which handles the event rather than having an event handler for every child element.

Say for example you have a div with 1000 'a' elements in it. Instead of having 1000 event handlers (one for each element) you can have one event handler on the parent div and choose 'a' as the selector.

It is also useful for dynamic elements which get added to the page at some point in the future.

Comment: `.on()` doesn't only do delegated events. The purpose of `.on()` is to attach event handlers for all situations, both directly to individual elements and to parent/ancestor elements for delegated event handling. That is, `.on()` can do what `.live()` _and_ `.delegate()` _and_ `.bind()` did.

Answer (score 0):

One example is when data comes into the html page after this page was loaded. So for example you have a

news1 info Go go news 1

news2 info Go go news 2

and then you append to  with ajax

news3 info Go go news 3. Before using ajax you had:

```
$(function(){
    $("p").css({border: "3px solid #c00"});
});
```

When news3 will be loaded the paragraph won't get a 3px solid #c00 border, because the property was applied to all paragraphs before this one was loaded.
In this case using live jQuery function will ensure that the new loaded news paragraph will get the desired border properties. Example code:

```
$(function(){
        $("p").live("click", function (e) {
            $(this).css({border: "3px solid #c00"});
        });
});
```

Final example here, click the button to add more paragraphs, then click the paragraphs to get the border effect:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    p { background:yellow; font-weight:bold; cursor:pointer; padding:5px; }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="submit" value="Add paragraph" id="addp"></span>
<p>Initial paragraph 1!</p>
<p>Initial paragraph 2!</p>
<p>Initial paragraph 3!</p>
<script>
$("#addp").click(function(){
    $(this).after("<p>Another paragraph!</p>");
});
$("p").css({border: "3px solid #c00"});
$("p").live("click", function (e) {
    $(this).css({border: "3px solid #c00"});
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ImranJawaid It's also entirely incorrect - live is for adding event handlers to elements. The second code snippet using `.live()` will simply give you a Javascript error.

Comment: I've added extra example and also tested them before, they work 100%

Answer (score 0):

Event handlers attached with `.live()` or `.delegate()` will be triggered for elements that match the selector *at the time the event occurs*, potentially including elements that didn't exist at the time the binding was setup.

Event handlers attached with `.bind()` or `.click()` (or other shortcut event methods like `.keyup()` or `.submit()`) will be triggered for the elements that matched the selector *at the time the binding was made* - even if those elements no longer match the selector at the time the event occurs.

The `.on()` method introduced in jQuery 1.7 can setup either kind of event handler depending on the parameters you pass it.

In your case most likely using `.live()` worked where `.click()` didn't because either

- the script block where that code sits appears before the element in your html and thus the element hasn't been parsed yet and can't be found for an immediate binding (in which case you could fix it by moving the script block after the element and/or by putting the code in a document.ready handler), or
- the element was created dynamically after the code ran

For more info read the [jQuery events doco](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/).

Answer (score 0):

you use `live()` when your container DOM will be modified and you want to capture events on new elements as well.

The function live() is deprecated, so I'll recommend you to upgrade your code to use the new `on()` function instead.

```
$('#Register').on('click', function (e) {
    $("#storytellerregistration").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Read the docs for on() function in the [API's docs site](http://api.jquery.com/on/)