# Condition onclick jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an href indeed an onclick with some condition. Can I block an href if these conditions is not respected ? If the all conditions is respected, I want that the href run...

```
<a class="btn btn-small" href="page2.php" onclick="verification()">Valid</a>
```

Here the conditions in jquery it's like that :

```
function verification()
{
    var player = 10;
    if(player <= 10)
    {
      alert('OK');
    }
    else
    {
      alert('NO');

    }
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: href="javascript:void()"

Comment: what are the conditions?

Comment: You have jQuery: *why* are you using `onclick` (even *without* jQuery you shouldn't be using `onclick`...)?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have tagged this question with Jquery, I would suggest you to use `e.preventDefault()` in this occassion.

HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-small" href="page2.php">Valid</a>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('a.btn').click(function(e){
 //I just assumed that you would add some real conditions over here. 
 if(!condition){ e.preventDefault(); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" id="linkidhere">Valid</a>
```

Then in JS:

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '#linkidhere', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    if (linkIsValid())
    {
      window.location.href = url;
    }
  };
});


function linkIsValid(){
  //...do validation stuff, returning true or false
}
```

Comment: Actually I have just seen Rajaprabhu's answer and that is probably a better way of doing it.